# Problems with Visual Studio c# and Restclient httpwebrequests / Postman

Tags: c#, get, postman, httpwebrequest, patch

I try to make some httpwebrequests with VS C#. The API on the server works with GET and PATCH requests. First i have tested every request with Postman and everything works fine. Then i try to test it in VS (Export C# Restapi and also with httpwebrequest. The result is that the GET requests works fine but on the PATCH requests i get not response (Timeout). There is no exception. It looks like the server is just waiting.

The RestApi Code from Postman:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://192.168.10.13/Service.dll/v1/terminal");

client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("api_auth", "123456");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var body = @"{" + "\n" + @"    ""status"": ""service""" + "\n" + @"}";

request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The client hangs in Line 11 while waiting on a response. After the timeout the response is empty.

Is it possible to capture the whole request to see whats different between Postman and VS?
Could it be a problem with the validation of the server certificate. I have to delegate the validation to true. But this works with the GET requests.

Im still hanging like my requests. Can someone help me with this problem. I have no idea anymore.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like response.Content.ReadAsync() or response.Content.ToString()? I don't know RestAPI, but using standard HttpClient it's something like that.

Comment: I also tried it async. The same result.